# Why does my loop that relies on an overflowed integer work differently across different computers?

Tags: c, debugging, integer-overflow

My code is as follows:

```
void findten ()
    {
        int x = 1, power = 0;
        printf("10^%d, x = %d\n", power++, x);
        while((x*10)/10 == x)
        {
            x *= 10;
            printf("10^%d, x = %d\n", power++, x);
        }
    }
```

The idea is that the loop should stop when x > 10e9 because of the maximum integer value. When I first ran and compiled this it worked just fine, and it continues to on the computer I first wrote it on. Let's call this computer A.

On another computer, computer B, I compiled the same file containing the function and it does not work, instead running an infinite loop where x ends up being equal to 0. I'm confused why this has happened.

The function is indeed the same in both cases.

The correct output which computer A gives me:

```
10^0, x = 1
10^1, x = 10
10^2, x = 100
10^3, x = 1000
10^4, x = 10000
10^5, x = 100000
10^6, x = 1000000
10^7, x = 10000000
10^8, x = 100000000
10^9, x = 1000000000
```

Computer B lists the same output but then keeps going on and overflows the int. Eventually x = 0 at some point, for a reason I do not understand.

Comment: Undefined behavior for signed integer overflow. Since your loop would only terminate if `x*10` overflowed, and such overflow would be undefined behavior, the compiler can conclude that the loop will never terminate, and consequently the loop condition can be optimized out and the loop be converted to `while(true)...`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Integer-Overflow-Basics.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So going forward should I assume there is no standard for integer overflow? Any good source on this I can check out?

Comment: @qq the drafts of the ISO c standards are publicly available for free. The c11 draft standard document n1570 has this to say: *6.5 Expressions 5 If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the
result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its
type), the behavior is undefined.* Note that operations on *unsigned* types explicitly do not cause undefined behavior in such cases: *6.2.5 Types 9 [...] A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow[...]*

Comment: @EOF thanks again, you really helped me out. I ended up finding a draft of the ISO c standard for things in the future. I'm new to stackoverflow and I wish I could mark your comment as resolving my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that signed integer overflow causes undefined behaviour. Therefore, `x * 10 / 10 == x` is a trouble if `x * 10` is more than INT_MAX.

I assume that the way of representing signed ints on one of your computers wraps int on overflow but the other one doesn't.